Custom utility for applying Material Icons font variation settings in Tailwind CSS?
I'm trying to create a utility in Tailwind CSS for easily applying font variation settings to Material Icons, similar to how it's done in regular CSS. For example, in regular CSS, I can apply font variation settings to a class like this:
.material-symbols-rounded {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 700;
}

Where fill can be 0 or 1 and wght can be from 100 to 700. How can I achieve the same result in Tailwind CSS with a utility class?

take a look here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3225
